# Asp.net session doesn't seem to work with WCF WebHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, session, webhttpbinding

We're doing a WCF REST json service (WebHttpBinding). Since pure WCF session doesn't work with this kind of binding, we are using asp.net session. So we set:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

In our web.config, and :

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

On top of our service implementation.
We have several service methods such as:

```
public void OpenSession(string userName)
public void GetSomething(int somethingId)
public void CloseSession()
```

Then we test the sessionId of the HttpContext in each method.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

Problem is: it's always changing.
If I make a call to **OpenSession?userName='toto'** in my web browser, and another one right after to **GetSomething?somethingId=1234**, the session id will change.

It seems that the cookies aren't well handled by wcf. If I call the OpenSession method in fiddler, in the http headers, there're no 'Set-Cookie' returned by the service.

Answer (score 1):

I found that :

> By default, WCF does not have cookie
>   enabled on the client side. So when
>   the server requires Cookie, you need
>   to turn on the cookie on the binding
>   for the client through the property
>   HttpTransportBindingElement.AllowCookies.

It's in this article. Checki if it will be usefull for you : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx

Comment: It returns null. Maybe because ASP compatibility is enabled.

Comment: The issue is not on the client side. The client in my case is a smartphone web browser or a desktop web browser. Cookies are already enabled in them.

Comment: Broken link in this answer